# Why SCOPE_IDENTITY returns NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure that take `@dbName` and insert record in that DB.
I want to get the id of the last inserted record. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns NULL and `@@IDENTITY` returns correct id, why it happens? As I read, so it's better to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in case there are some triggers on the table. 
Can I use `IDENT_CURRENT`? Does it return the id in the scope of the table, regardless of trigger?

So what is the problem and what to use?

**EDITED**

```
DECALRE @dbName nvarchar(50) = 'Site'
DECLARE @newId int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@dbName) + N'..myTbl(IsDefault) ' +
           N'VALUES(0)'     
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Just a note on why I downvoted your question.  From the comments below, it appears that you edited your question after answers were provided, making the answers seem confusing.  There's no shame in not knowing how to do something.  Leave your learning process public so that others may learn from it.  As it is now, someone else who has this problem will now not be able to use your experience to learn from.

Comment: @Ben, I'm not agree with you. There is nothing to do with '...shame in not knowing...'. I explained why I edited my post when answering to Martin. I mistakenly wrote them HERE in wrong order. In my code(at home) I wrote them in correct order. I ask you to upvote my question please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like Oded says, the problem is that you're asking for the identity before you execute the `insert`.

As a solution, it's best to run `scope_identity` as close to the `insert` as you can.  By using `sp_executesql` with an output parameter, you can run `scope_identity` as part of the dynamic SQL statement:

```
SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO ' + quotename(@dbName) + N'..myTbl(IsDefault) ' +
           N'VALUES(0) ' +
           N'SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@newId int output', @newId output
```

Here's an [example at SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/111578/) showing that `scope_identity` should be inside the `sp_executesql`.

Comment: The problem is different scope not the order of operations. The `sp_executesql` that does the insert is executing before the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` call (Edit: I see the OP has edited their question now making your first line appear wrong +1)

Comment: @Martin, I mistakenly wrote them in wrong order. In my code I wrote them in correct order. Anyway, I edited my post

Comment: @Andomar, I edited my code. Why I need to insert SCOPE_IDENTITY to @sql? Why I cannot call it after sp_executesql?

Comment: @theateist: Code inside `sp_executesql` runs in a different "scope".  (Don't be tempted to use `@@identity`; it might solve this problem, but it'll leave you with a heap of others.)

Comment: Does SQL Server sometimes re-order operations?  I've got an intermittent (and rare) instance where I get a null from SCOPE_IDENTITY() that immediately follows the insert...

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function will return the `null` value if the function is invoked before any `INSERT` statements into an identity column occur in the scope.