# Bug in ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer and GetLastInsertId when using InsertParam?

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

To exemplify the problem, I have a simple table with a PK that is AUTOINCREMENT. When I use the Insert, GetLastInsertId works as it should, ie returns the key value of the inserted row, but not when I use InsertParam. Then the key value is 0. When I look in the database, everything looks good.

My installed version is https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/3.9.56.

Example code

```
public class Foo
{
   public Foo() {}

   [AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string SomeText { get; set; }
}
```

Insert - GetLastInsertId is working correct

```
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.Insert(new Foo { SomeText = "Bla bla" } );
    string sql = db.GetLastSql();      
    // sql = "INSERT INTO \"Foo\" (\"SomeText\") VALUES (N'Bla bla')"

    int id = (int)db.GetLastInsertId();
    // id = 1
    sql = db.GetLastSql();
    // sql = SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
}
```

InsertParam - GetLastInsertId is NOT working correct (always 0!!!)

```
using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
{
    db.InsertParam(new Foo { SomeText = "Bla bla" } );
    string sql = db.GetLastSql();
    // sql = "INSERT INTO \"Foo\" (\"SomeText\") VALUES (@SomeText)"

    int id = (int)db.GetLastInsertId();
    // id = 0 (always 0)
    sql = db.GetLastSql();
    // sql = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
}
```

Has anyone else seen the same problem with ORMLite and SQL Server?

When I view the source code for ORMLite and SQL server and project ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServerTests I see the class InsertParam_GetLastInsertId with test case Can_GetLastInsertedId_using_InsertParam. Should give an assert, I think?

I've just verified the error by running NUnit and I got the expected error on line 31

```
ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServerTests.
InsertParam_GetLastInsertId.
Can_GetLastInsertedId_using_InsertParam:
   with InsertParam
   Expected: greater than 0
   But was:  0
```

Answer (score 3):

I have investigated this failed unit test and it is related to this question [Why SCOPE_IDENTITY returns NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298030/why-scope-identity-returns-null).
I have made a [pull request on OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/pull/300) to fix this. I will keep you informed if it gets accepted.

Demis Bellot altered my solution and merged a fix in the main branch. InsertParam can now directly return the lastinsertedid.

```
public static long InsertParam<T>(this IDbConnection dbConn, T obj, bool selectIdentity = false)
```

This is now available in v3.9.58